# Get two classes in one query with parse.com

Tags: php, parse-platform

I currently have a `class` called **Activity** and another called **Video**.

The `Activity class` contains the **object ID** for the video `class`.

When I query 8 activity rows and its associated video, it heavily slows my PHP script down from **1 second**, to around **10 seconds**.

Is there a way I can query for both classes in one row, like a `MySQL` `join` query?

Hereis my code

```
    $query = new ParseQuery("Activity");

    $query->containedIn("type","video");

    $query->limit($limit);
    $comments = $query->find();

    if(!$queryResults){
        return false;
    }

    foreach($queryResults as $result){

        if($result->get("type") == "post"){

            $content = array(
                "objectId"          =>  $contentQuery->getObjectId(),
                "name"              =>  $contentQuery->get("name"),
                "location"      =>  $contentQuery->get("location")
            );
        }

        $return[] = array(
            "activityObjectId"  =>  $result->getObjectId(),
            "type"              =>  $result->get("type"),
            "content"           =>  $content,
            "user"              =>  $this->user,
            "createdAt"         =>  $result->get("createdAt")
        );
    }
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: You should start with providing more information in this question like the code of **Activity**, or the **query** you are using.

Comment: Not that I think it was necessary due to the nature of this question, but I have added my code.

Comment: Parse does not allow you to cross-query classes, naturally, since they are a business that collects revenue from API requests. Parse does have a orQueryWithSubQueries but again, it's not for cross-referencing different classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better design is to replace the string col containing the related object id with a pointer column containing the object (virtually speaking).

The assignment is simpler (in JS, say):

```
// change this
myActivity.set("videoIDString", myVideo.id);
// to this
myActivity.set("video", myVideo);
```

...where 'video' is a pointer type column, pointing to the Video class.

Having done this, you can get activities and their associated videos by telling the query to eagerly fetch the video pointer:

```
$query->includeKey("video");
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks you :D